# pip install scipy==1.4.1 on mac os

Tags: python, installation, pip, scipy

I have created a new virtual environment with nothing else in it and I try to install

```
pip install scipy==1.4.1
```

However this returns the following error

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed to build scipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scipy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

This has been solved before by running

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

However this does not work for me and I get the same error as before. If however I try and install the latest version of scipy there are no issues. Does anyone know a way around this? Maybe I need a less up to date version of python but I am really not sure.

Comment: why do you need older version? Did you check documentation for `scipy` ? It may have information what Python version needs `scipy 1.4.1`. Did you check this error in Gooogle? maybe someone had this problem before.

Comment: I have googled this error and people have had the same error caused by not having the most up to date version of pip. However this doesn't fix my issue. I was hoping someone might know the answer. I don't know if i need an older version, I was just guessing that this might be the answer

Comment: maybe it needs other modules for installing `scipy` - ie module `wheel` or something like `setuptools`? Or maybe it need some C/C++ files to compile it. Is this FULL error message? You should show full error message - there can be other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your python version is too new for this specific scipy version, use a earlier python version to solve the problem.

1. Install a specific python version (i.e. 3.7.4) from https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Create virtual environment with pipenv:
   pipenv shell --python 3.7.4
   (and activate virtual environment)
3. Install scipy==1.4.1